# Convert PHP date format

Tags: php

I have a simple section in which a user can select a range of date.

PHP to get these dates from datepicker

```
if (isset($_POST['from_date']) && isset($_POST['to_date'])) {
  $firstDate= $_POST['from_date'];
  $lastDate= $_POST['to_date'];
   var_dump($firstDate);
   var_dump($lastDate);

}
```

From the above PHP script, I am getting this

```
string(10) "08/13/2019"
string(10) "08/14/2019"
```

But I want this

```
string(10) "2019-08-13"
string(10) "2019-08-14"
```

What do I need to do to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtotime() :

```
$time = strtotime('08/13/2019');

$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);

echo $newformat;
// 2019-08-13
```